# How to identify view with NSString tag?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

view.tag is only stored NSInteger Value.

so, how to identify each view with NSString Value?

not avaliable?

some example:

```
view0.stringTag = @"basic";

view1.stringTag = @"advanced";
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no `stringTag` property on `UIView`. If you need to do this kind of thing you can use a category on `UIView` and store the tag in an associated object:

```
@interface UIView (StringTagAdditions)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringTag;
@end

@implementation UIView (StringTagAdditions)
static NSString *kStringTagKey = @"StringTagKey";
- (NSString *)stringTag
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kStringTagKey);
}
- (void)setStringTag:(NSString *)stringTag
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kStringTagKey, stringTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe what about viewWithTag method because it get's integer value as parameter?- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag;

Comment: For those using Swift, another cool solution would be to use an extension

Comment: This was useful, thanks! I had to change `static NSString *kStringTagKey = @"StringTagKey";` to `static const char *kStringTagKey = "StringTagKey";
`

Answer (score 7):

```
if use ARC

#import "UIView.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView (StringTagAdditions)
static NSString *kStringTagKey = @"StringTagKey";
- (NSString *)stringTag
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, CFBridgingRetain(kStringTagKey));
}
- (void)setStringTag:(NSString *)stringTag
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, CFBridgingRetain(kStringTagKey), stringTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't use a string. If you are aiming for code readability, you could use an enum. Be sure to start your enum from 1, though, as 0 is the default tag for all views:

```
typedef enum {
    vtBasic = 1,
    vtAdvanced
} ViewType;
...
view0.tag = vtBasic;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`restorationIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/restorationIdentifier).

```
// Supposing iOS 6.0+
view0.restorationIdentifier = @"basic";
view1.restorationIdentifier = @"advanced";
```

Comment: Hijacking `restorationIdentifier` for this might interfere with unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

it's not supported directly. you could of course create a C array, a NSArray, a NSDictionary, or something like that to accomplish this (in conjunction with the int tag).

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you subclass your own UIView with a stringTag property. What is your reason for doing this?

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution by far: [Link to my answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594610/store-additional-associated-infomation-in-a-uiview/28531254#28531254)

Try setting the accessibility identifier property of your UIView:

```
UIView *view;
view.accessibilityIdentifier = @"your string here";
NSLog(@"%@", view.accessibilityIdentifier);
```

Output => your string here

This behaves just like the "tag" property but allows you to use NSString

Comment: It's a misuse of the API

Comment: What's the use? (no pun intended) @AdamWaite

Answer (score -2):

First, you never use tags as it is. Always do it like this possibly in a .h file(best practice, IMHO. ):

```
#define MY_VIEW_A 10001
#define MY_VIEW_B 10002
```

Then, when creating views:

```
view0.tag = MY_VIEW_A
view1.tag = MY_VIEW_B
```

Then, where you want to find the view:

```
UIView *viewA = [mainView viewWithTag:MY_VIEW_A]; //this will be the view0 you created.
```

Alternatively,  you can define a hash function that converts NSString to some Integer that can be assigned as a tag. E.g.

```
- (int) tagForName:(NSString*)name;
```

and then also,

```
- (NSString*) nameForTag:(int)tag;
```

I leave it up to you to [define the hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010875/string-to-integer-hashing-function-with-precision).

Comment: Using enums is a far better way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to compare NSStrings,

```
if([view0.stringTag isEqualToString:@"basic"]){
  // 
}
```

as like

```
if(view0.tag==0){
//
}
```

where stringTag is an NSString variable to be defined in the views and assigned value to compare