# Need an algorithm to generate an integer hash value for a String in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I am using `uthash.h` for hash implementation in C. I am using the hash-table for a basic word count exercise. I have a file containing words and I have to count frequency of each word. The implementation of `uthash.h` requires me to generate an integer id for each entry, and I wanted to calculate a unique integer corresponding to each string. I tried using md5 hash algorithm, but it generates strings with digits and alphabets, so its no use.Can anybody suggest me such an algorithm.

Comment: A good implementation of the md5 hash should be able to give you the raw 16-byte array. Split this into 4 32bit integers and xor them together. That alphanumeric string is just a convent representation for displaying the hash.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521148/string-to-unique-integer-hashing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010875/string-to-integer-hashing-function-with-precision.

Comment: @user1929959, the  second link that you mentioned has hashing functions that return unsigned long values, but in `uthash.h` implementation the id needs to be integer. I am not wether this will work or not. I will try this approach and post my results once done. In the mean time if you have any more suggestion, please post them.

Comment: I head [murmur3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) is pretty good for strings.

Comment: And please don't use md5 or any other cryptographic hash function for this. Their computation is *much* slower than good non-cryptographic hash functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Robert Sedgewick's [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sedgewick_%28computer_scientist%29) for hashing

```
unsigned int GenerateHash(char* str, unsigned int len)
{
   unsigned int result = 0;
   unsigned int b    = 378551;
   unsigned int a    = 63689;
   unsigned int i    = 0;

   for(i=0; i<len; str++, i++)
   {
      result = result*a + (*str);
      a = a*b;
   }

   return result;
}
```